# How to configure Odata api for show result from table or stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, odata

I am going to create an Odata api in asp.net mvc 4 for get data from new table. when I call the Odata method and use debug in the code It shows me data properly. But when it comes to browser, it shows empty screen. 
There is no error shown in the code.

this is my Odata method :

```
[Queryable]
    public HCPData GetHCPData([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
      //  return SingleResult.Create(db.HCPDatas.Where(hcpdata => hcpdata.Id == key));
        IQueryable<HCPData> result = db.HCPDatas.Where(p => p.CompanyId == key);
        return result.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

this is my WebApiConfig method:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

         ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        //var entitySetConfiguration1 = modelBuilder.EntitySet<Job>("Job");
         var entitySetConfiguration1 = modelBuilder.EntitySet<HCPData>("HCPData");


         var customer = modelBuilder.EntityType<HCPData>();

         modelBuilder.EntitySet<HCPData>("HCPData");


        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: null,
            model: modelBuilder.GetEdmModel());
    }
```

When I checked the console of empty screen in browser it shows an error: "NetworkError: 406 Not Acceptable - http://localhost:50369/HCPData?key=11"

Please let me know the solution of the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What's the result if you change the controller as follows:

```
public class HCPDataController : ODataController
{
   [EnableQuery]
   public HCPData GetHCPData([FromODataUri] int key)
   {
    ...
   }
}
```

#### [My Sample]

Because, at my side, if I implement the controller as follows, it can work:

```
[EnableQuery]
public HCPData GetHCPData([FromODataUri] int key)
{
     var data = new HCPData
     {
         CompanyId = 2,
         Name = "Key = " + key
     };

     return data;
}
```

#### Example:

Let me issue the following request:

[image]

I can get the following response:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:62591/odata/$metadata#HCPData/$entity","CompanyId":2,"Name":"Key = 11"
}
```